# Error starting SQL Server 2017 service. Error Code 3417

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have SQL Server 2017 installed on my computer. This is what `SELECT @@VERSION` returns:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)   Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 17134: )`

It was working fine until yesterday. Suddenly `SQL SERVER Service` did not run. When I wanted to run the service manually it showed `3417 error`. When I checked event log I saw this error:

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.`

After some googling I found out I can run it with `/T902 switch` and try to fix the problem. But no solution worked for me. So I installed another instance of the same `SQL SERVER 2017` and restored databases. Now the new installed instance has the same problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try installing SQL Server 2017, do *not* allow it to search for updates online, and immediately afterwards apply [Cumulative Update 10](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4342123/cumulative-update-10-for-sql-server-2017) (the latest update). Do not restore any system databases. If applying the CU fails, you can investigate its setup log -- this scenario definitely works (on a vanilla Windows and non-broken hardware).